# Landsat 8 - eleven bands and corresponding files

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, landsat-8

Landsat 8 zipped file downloaded via EarthExplorer consists of several files.
Which of the files correspond to the band 8, 9, 11?

- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ANG.txt
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_MTL.json
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_MTL.txt
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_MTL.xml
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_QA_PIXEL.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_QA_RADSAT.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_SR_B1.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_SR_B2.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_SR_B3.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_SR_B6.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_SR_B7.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_SR_QA_AEROSOL.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_SR_stac.json
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_ATRAN.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_B10.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_CDIST.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_DRAD.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_EMIS.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_EMSD.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_QA.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_stac.json
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_TRAD.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_ST_URAD.TIF
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_thumb_large.jpeg
- LC09_L2SP_x_y_z_02_T1_thumb_small.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

You have downloaded a L2SP product which doesn't contain these bands anymore. See the documentation [here](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-landsat-archives-landsat-8-9-olitirs-collection-2-level-2) and [here](https://d9-wret.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/palladium/production/s3fs-public/media/files/LSDS-1619_Landsat8-9-Collection2-Level2-Science-Product-Guide-v5.pdf) (see page 12 for the content of L2SP products).

- Band 8 (PAN) is not processed for L2SP products
- Band 9 (cirrus) can be found in QA mask
- Band 11 (TIRS2) used in ST computation